# Resource.Designer.cs is not generated if a language code is used in the name

Tags: .net, resources, .net-core, resx, .net-standard-2.0

I am totally confused and I hope you can help me.

In my solution I use some resources (resx) for varios languages. 
In the past, the designer files were always generated, but suddenly it does not work anymore and I do not understand it.

as soon as a language code is used in the name, the designer file cannot be generated and following error appears:

```
Custom tool ResXFileCodeGenerator failed to produce an output for input file 'Resources\Resource1.cz.resx' but did not log a specific error.
```

I created some empty resource files:

- Resource.resx (is working)
- Resource.de.resx (not working)
- Resource.en.resx (not working)
- **Resource.HUGO.resx (is working)**

I tried it with VS 17 and VS 17 preview.

**EDIT: It just does not work in a .Net Standard Project**

**EDIT: Is working on VS for Mac with .Net Standard, but not on VS for Windows**

Any idea?

kind regards,
christoph

Comment: [Known problem](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1553).

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio 2019 in an asp.net core 3.1 webSite project (using Globalization), I faced this issue when I used an existing resource file.

To solve the issue:

1. Created a new Resource.resx. (Using Add>New Item...>Resorce
   File.resx .
2. Copy all contents of the first file in the new file (Copy
   all three columns).
3. Delete the old file.
4. Rename the new file to the intended name.

It worked for me. I wish it works for you too.